# android, save and restore user-input in webview

Tags: android, webview

Suppose a user is writing a blog in a webview.

He might leave the app for a while to google something and come back to finish up the writing.
He might load up another activity to select photos and attach it to the blogs.

When he comes back, he expects to see the text he already inputted. 
But he sees blank textview sometimes when he comes back.

I'm thinking of saving/restoring in the `onResume` but is there a better spot to do so?